# Why doesn't Bazel find my include file despite using copts to add an extra include directory?

Tags: gcc, bazel

I've modified the stage3 cpp bazelbuild example to use an extra include paths via `copts`

https://github.com/mnieber/examples/commit/a8b784ddf5698563a31401b9ac3531636b3536ef

However, this produces a compiler error (note though that `-Ilib/foo` is used as an option for `gcc`):

```
bazel build --verbose_failures //main:hello-world
INFO: Analysed target //main:hello-world (1 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/maarten/sources/examples/cpp-tutorial/stage3/lib/BUILD:1:1: C++ compilation of rule '//lib:hello-time' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/maarten/.cache/bazel/_bazel_maarten/62d72ea3bd73864cf884808e7d850715/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib \
    PATH=/home/maarten/projects/xmlparser/dodo_commands/env/bin:/home/maarten/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dodo/env/bin:/home/maarten/.dodo_commands/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/lib/_objs/hello-time/hello-time.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/lib/_objs/hello-time/hello-time.pic.o' -fPIC -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -Ilib/foo -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c lib/hello-time.cc -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/lib/_objs/hello-time/hello-time.pic.o)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
lib/hello-time.cc:2:21: fatal error: bar/baz.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Target //main:hello-world failed to build
```

Can someone explain why `bar/baz.h` is not found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this answer on the Bazel mailing list (short version: this header file needs to be added to `srcs`, somewhat surprisingly):

The problem is that you do not declare the header file baz.h in any way among the sources of the cc_library. So, when the execution is happening in the sandbox (the default), the file is not visible. The build already works without the sandbox (try running it with --spawn_strategy=standalone flag).

So, declare the baz.h in the sources:

```
cc_library(
    name = "hello-time",
    srcs = [
        "foo/bar/baz.h",
        "hello-time.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = ["hello-time.h"],
    copts = ["-Ilib/foo"],
    visibility = ["//main:__pkg__"],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cc_library` in `cpp-tutorial/stage3/lib/BUILD` does not declare a dependency on the header file, so Bazel does not put that file into the sandbox, so the compilation fails (as it should).

You don't need the extra `copts`. Instead you either have to add `bar/baz.h` to the `hdrs` of the "hello-time" rule, or, in case "bar" is a separate package (it has a BUILD file) then add a "cc_library" rule whose `hdrs` includes `baz.h` and depend on this library from "hello-time".