# bazel build c++ project failed with *.h could not find

Tags: c++, compilation, bazel

my project A is relying on brpc:https://github.com/apache/incubator-brpc

projectA.WORKSPACE:

```
git_repository(
        name = "brpc",
        # remote = "https://github.com/apache/incubator-brpc.git",
        remote = "git@github.com:apache/incubator-brpc.git",
        commit = "c4de79975ea54684634d1e52d4691f96d134d34a",
        shallow_since = "1671716289 +0800"
    )
```

projectA.classB BUILD

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")


cc_library(
    name = "client",
    srcs = glob([
        "*.cpp",
    ]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "*.h",
    ]),
    deps = [ "@brpc//:brpc"
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

thrid_party/brpc BUILD

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "brpc",
    srcs = glob([
        "src/brpc/*.cpp",
        "src/bthread/*.cpp",
        "src/brpc/*.h",
    ]),
    deps = [
    ],
    includes = [
        ".",
    ],
    include_prefix = "brpc",
    strip_include_prefix = "brpc",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

bazel build msg:

```
INFO: Invocation ID: 9aae1a04-1225-4f62-9780-d334df616f9a
WARNING: errors encountered while analyzing target '//client:client': it will not be built
INFO: Analysis succeeded for only 1 of 2 top-level targets
INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (19 packages loaded, 56 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //third_party/brpc:brpc up-to-date (nothing to build)
ERROR: command succeeded, but not all targets were analyzed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.262s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

still can not find *.h in brpc

figure out which bazel config is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the above issue because there might not be visibility of the header (.h) file to the sandbox and it gets fail. Try adding the files as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997911/why-doesnt-bazel-find-my-include-file-despite-using-copts-to-add-an-extra-inclu). Please reach if that did not resolve your issue.